# Read certain bits from one register and write into certain bits of another

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, operators, bit, bit-shift

I am looking to implement the prototype for read_and_write, but couldn't get it right. Any help is appreciated. I am able to extract bits.

In this below code for write_val1, my intent is to write only the first 9 bits of final_val into read_data. The rest 7 bits of read_data should remain untouched. Expected output for write_val1 = 0x0080

Similarly for write_val2, my intent is to write only next 8 bits from final_val into read_data. The rest 8 bits of read_data should remain untouched.
Expected output for write_val2 = 0x2700

Similarly for write_val3, my intent is to write only next 3 bits(010) from final_val into a position[11:13] of read_data leaving rest of read_data untouched.

> Expected output = 0x5448 ; For example: pick 010 extracted bit from
> write_val3; 0x3048 = 01**11 0**000 0100 1000;  0x5048 = 01**01 0**000
> 0100 1000

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

 // Extracts n bits from a given position in LSB. 
int bitExtracted(uint16_t read_data, uint8_t n_bits, uint8_t pos) 
{ 
    return (((1 << n_bits) - 1) & (read_data >> (pos - 1))); 
} 

void read_and_write(uint32_t* final_val, uint16_t* write_val, uint8_t start_pos, uint8_t end_pos)
{
    uint32_t temp = *final_val;
    *write_val = (uint16_t) ((temp >> start_pos) & ((1 << end_pos) - 1)); // store the desired number of bits in write_val
    *final_val = (temp >> end_pos); //shift final_val by end_pos since those bits are already written
    printf("\n temp %x, write_val %x, final_val %x ", temp, *write_val, *final_val);
    
}

void main() 
{
    uint16_t read_data = 0x0; //assume some read value
    uint16_t ext_val1 = bitExtracted(read_data, 9, 1);  //Read BITS [8:0] from read_data
    uint8_t ext_val2 = bitExtracted(read_data, 8, 1);   //Read BITS [7:0] from read_data
    uint8_t ext_val3 = bitExtracted(read_data, 3, 5);   //Read BITS [7:4] from read_data
    uint32_t final_val = 0x0; //Stores 20 extracted bits from val1, val2 and val3 into final_val (LSB to MSB in order)
    uint16_t write_val1, write_val2, write_val3;
    uint8_t start_pos = 0, end_pos =8;
    ext_val1 = 0x80, ext_val2 = 0x0, ext_val3 = 0x2;
    final_val = (ext_val1 | (ext_val2 << 9) | (ext_val3 << 17));
    printf ("\n final_val %x", final_val);
    
    //Read first 9 bits of final_val and write only into [8:0] position of existing read_data
    read_and_write(&final_val, &write_val1, 0, 9); 
    read_data = 0x80;
    write_val1 = write_val1 | read_data;
    
    //Read next 8 bits of final_val and write only into [7:0] position of existing read_data
    start_pos = 0;
    end_pos = 7;
    read_data = 0x27b7;
    read_and_write(&final_val, &write_val2, start_pos, end_pos);
    write_val2 = write_val2 | read_data;

    //Read next 3 bits of final_val and write only into[13:11] position of existing read_data
    start_pos = 11;
    end_pos = 13;
    read_data = 0x3048;
    read_and_write(&final_val, &write_val3, start_pos, end_pos);
    write_val3 = write_val3 | read_data;
    printf ("\n val1 0x%x val2 0x%x val3 0x%x final_val 0x%x", write_val1, write_val2, ext_val3, final_val);
}
```

Comment: In the function `bitExtracted`, what is the meaing of the function parameters `n_bits` and `pos`? Is `pos` the position of the first bit to extract and `n_bits` the total number of bits to extract? Is `pos` a zero-based index or a one-based index? In other words, is the position of the [least significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit) `0` or `1`? And what exactly does the comment `Read BITS [8:0]` mean? Does that mean you want to extract bit 0 (least significant bit) up to and including bit 8?

Comment: I have assumed it as one-based index. Read BITS [8:0] implies that I want to extract bit 0 upto 8 including bit 8.

Comment: Just as a side note: `(1 << n_bits) - 1` will not work with `n_bits == 16` on platforms on which `sizeof(int) == 2`, i.e. on 16-bit platforms. This size is permitted by the ISO C standard. However, on most modern platforms, `sizeof(int) >= 4`, so it should not be a problem. See [integer promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) for further information.

Comment: @ManaswiSingh final_val already has the values stored. I need to write to only write_val1, write_val2, write_val3; which would be extracted from final_val.

Comment: @ManaswiSingh. I have assumed that final_val already has the values written in order. I haven't added code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `read_and_write()` function to be able to change the values of the first two inputs to the function, (e.g. `final_val` and `write_val1`), then they should be passed as pointers to the function. Your function prototype should thus look like this:

`void read_and_write(uint32_t* final_val, uint16* write_val1, uint8_t start_pos, uint8_t end_pos);`

When calling the function in your main code, you need to use `&` to take the address of the variables. So you call them using:

`read_and_write(&final_val, &write_val1, start_pos, end_pos);`

For the reading and writing portion, it is pretty much similar to what you did in the `bitExtracted` function.

```
uint32_t temp = *final_val;
*write_val = (uint16_t) ((temp >> start_pos) & ((1 << end_pos) - 1)); // store the desired number of bits in write_val

*final_val = (temp >> end_pos); //shift final_val by end_pos since those bits are already written
```

The `*` is to deference the pointer and access the data stored in a particular location. Note that you also need to have a `(uint16_t)` cast for `write_val` since the type needs to match.